# How do I find all records with timestamp older than 120 days ago in h2

Tags: sql, h2

```
select * from myTable where REC_CREA < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - 120 days
```

Im having trouble converting from db2 sql to h2.How would I get records older than 120 days in h2?

Comment: Use `REC_CREA < DATEADD(DAY, -120, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())`

Comment: DATE_SUB function not found

Comment: What exactly is the data type of your column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEADD()`. For example:

```
select * 
from t 
where rec_crea < dateadd(day, -120, current_timestamp());
```

Example script:

```
create table t (name varchar(10), rec_crea datetime);

insert into t (name, rec_crea) values ('Anne', '2020-06-01');
insert into t (name, rec_crea) values ('Louisa', '2021-01-07');
```

Result:

```
NAME        REC_CREA       
----  ---------------------
Anne  2020-06-01 00:00:00.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a some recent version of H2, use standard-compliant

```
select * from myTable where REC_CREA < LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '120' DAY
```

for `TIMESTAMP` column, (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '120' DAY` for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column or `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '120' DAY` for `DATE` column).

If you use H2 1.4.197 or older version, use

```
select * from myTable where REC_CREA < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 120
```

Don't use this legacy syntax in newer versions, it isn't officially supported.